# how to print the whole string of the user input?

Tags: java

I am trying to print the whole string of the user input. In the code, for example, the user enters "golden retriever" but would only print "golden's" but want everything that the user inputs. I had tried the .nextLine but will only print the next line which is "System.out.println(breed + "'s" + " are AWESOME!");"

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Registration {
        static void PetWelcome() {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Pet's name: ");
            String name = scan.next().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Welcome, " + name + "!");
            System.out.println(name + ", we need more details about you.");
        
            System.out.print("What is your age in months?: ");
            int age = scan.nextInt();
            
            if(age < 3) {
                System.out.println("Too young to join the shelter.");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You meet the age requirement! Keep on going!");
            } 
            String petType;
            
            do {
                System.out.print("Are you a dog or a cat?: ");
                petType = scan.next().toUpperCase();
                break;
            } while(!petType.equals("cat") && (!petType.equals("dog")));
            
            // the issue
            System.out.print("What is your breed? ");
            String breed = scan.next().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(breed + "'s" + " are AWESOME!");
    
            System.out.println("Thank you, " + name + " for taking the time to apply!");
        }
            
            static void OwnerInformation() {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Now we need the owner's information");
            System.out.print("What is your name?: ");
            String ownerName = scan.next();
    
            System.out.print("What is your phone number?: ");
            boolean flag;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                String phonePattern = "\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
                String input = sc.next();
                flag = input.matches(phonePattern);
                if (!flag) System.out.println("Enter phone number in ###-###-#### format.");
            } while (!flag);
            
            System.out.print("Enter your e-mail address: ");
            boolean flag2;
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15}[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}";
                String input = sc1.next();
                flag2 = input.matches(emailPattern);
                if (!flag2) System.out.println("Invalid email.");
            } while (!flag2);
        }

    
        
}
```

Comment: `nextLine()` is the correct, but incomplete answer; be aware of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/85421)

Answer (score 0):

Using `nextLine()` will fetch wathever user entered before hittig `enter` key. By using `next()` function you are only reading until a delimiter which is space in this case. It is the same for `nextInt()`. User enter a number and hit `enter`. There would be a number and an end of line charachter like `\n`. This charachter isn't readed in `nextInt()` and would be fetch by you next reading. That is why your code ain't read what you inteand to read.

This should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Pet's name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Welcome, " + name + "!");
        System.out.println(name + ", we need more details about you.");

        System.out.print("What is your age in months?: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if(age < 3) {
            System.out.println("Too young to join the shelter.");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You meet the age requirement! Keep on going!");
        }
        String petType;

        do {
            System.out.print("Are you a dog or a cat?: ");
            petType = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            break;
        } while(!petType.equals("cat".toUpperCase()) && (!petType.equals("dog".toUpperCase())));

        // the issue
        System.out.print("What is your breed? ");
        String breed = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(breed + "'s" + " are AWESOME!");

        System.out.println("Thank you, " + name + " for taking the time to apply!");
    }

    static void OwnerInformation() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Now we need the owner's information");
        System.out.print("What is your name?: ");
        String ownerName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("What is your phone number?: ");
        boolean flag;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String phonePattern = "\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            flag = input.matches(phonePattern);
            if (!flag) System.out.println("Enter phone number in ###-###-#### format.");
        } while (!flag);

        System.out.print("Enter your e-mail address: ");
        boolean flag2;
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15}[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}";
            String input = sc1.nextLine();
            flag2 = input.matches(emailPattern);
            if (!flag2) System.out.println("Invalid email.");
        } while (!flag2);
    }



}
```

Comment: I tried the .nextLine but it prints the next line

Comment: @eness What next line? when user hits `enter` system wont fetch any other input

Comment: it will print this statement "System.out.println(breed + "'s" + " are AWESOME!");"

Comment: @eness This should work

Comment: I tried it and it does work. But its the other code that I have that is messing it up. I'll have to find the bug and fix it. thank you!!

Comment: @SM2A Just putting up code that works without explaining the problem is not nearly as helpful, as you can tell, it didn't help the OP understand what was wrong with their code

Comment: @RuanMendes Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs as you hit the enter key, which is a newline \n character. nextInt() before consumes only the integer, but it skips the newline \n. Add an additional `scan.nextLine()` after you read the int, which can consume the \n
And after use `.nextLine` as you mentioned.